# finding index from sibling element onClick jquery

Tags: jquery, indexing, css-selectors

I have multiple divs with the same class name that dynamically populate a container.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content cancel"><button class="showModal"></button></div>
<div class="content cancel"><button class="showModal"></button></div>
<div class="content cancel"><button class="showModal"></button></div>
<div class="content cancel"><button class="showModal"></button></div>
<div class="content cancel"><button class="showModal"></button></div>
</div>
```

Each div.content has a button that will show a jqueryUI dialog.  Once the modal is launched, it has two buttons for save and cancel.  If cancel is clicked, an alert will show the index position of the div that launched the modal and remove the class "cancel" from the div.content container it was launched from.

```
<div class="modal">
<button class="save">save</button>
<button class="RemoveCancel">cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$(".modal").on("click", ".RemoveCancel", function () {

    var parent = $(this).closest(".content");
    var modalTest = $(".content").index(parent);
    $("div.content:nth-child(" + (modalTest + 1) + ")").removeClass("cancel");
    alert("div.content:nth-child(" + (modalTest + 1) + ")");
});
```

and for the modal

```
$(function () {
    $(".modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    });

 $(".showModal").live('click', function () {
        $(".modal").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $(".save, .RemoveCancel").live('click', function () {
        $(".modal").dialog("close");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks for any input, currently i'm getting a -1 value for the alert. If I leave out the selector for index it'll show however many divs are apart of the index.  I hope this makes sense, thank you again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Does this code currently work?

Comment: `closest` searches ancestor elements for a match but from your html `.content` does not contain any `.RemoveCancel` element.

Comment: @MrTsherman once the modal is launched it has a button with a class of "RemoveCancel", once clicked I was wanting it to remove the cancel class from the div that it initially launched from.

Comment: @Musa sorry for any confusion i'll re-edit for better clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restructure your code. This is the framework that I came up with. I think that you can leverage it for your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/v4dtL/

A few things:

Don't use `live`. It has been deprecated. Use `on` or `delegate` instead.

Add a class called modalized to the clicked element. This allows you to keep track of who launched the modal window without doing any funky DOM traversals.

Use jQuery's `index` to find out the index of the clicked element in relation to its siblings.

```
//when showmodal is clicked, add modalized class to the clicked element
$(".container").on('click', '.showModal', function() {
    $(".modal").show();
    $(this).addClass('modalized');
});

//I broke save and removecancel into separate event handlers so that they don't step on each others toes (order of operations)
$(".modal").on('click', '.save', function() {
    $(".modal").hide();
    $('.modalized').removeClass('modalized');
});

//Use Index() to find the modalized element in relation to its siblings
$(".modal").on("click", ".RemoveCancel", function() {        
    var index = $('.showModal').index($('.modalized'));
    alert(index);
    $(".modal").hide();    
    $('.modalized').removeClass('modalized');
});

​
```

jQuery's `data` object allows you to store information on an element. So you could do something like this. Untested.

```
$('.showModal').click( function() {
      //store clicked index
      var index = $(this).siblings().index($(this));
      $('.modal').show().data('clickedIndex', index);
});

$('.cancel').click( function() {
      //retrieve clicked index
      var index = $(this).closest('.modal').data('clickedIndex');
      alert(index);
      //get all showmodal buttons, but grab the one with matching index
      $('.showModal')[index].removeClass('foo');
});
```

Comment: I had to re-edit and add a bit of information I had left out. Thank you for your help, but hopefully the revised question above may be better clarification for you.

Comment: Very nice, one question though, is there anyway to just remove the class modalized from just one container at a time?  At the moment now if I have more than one container with the class modalized and I hit cancel, it removes it from all containers.  I would like to remove them one container at a time.  Thank you again!

Comment: I made the incorrect assumption that you could only have one modal window at a time. That complicates things. I would probably leverage jQuery's `data` object. You can use that to store which popup was triggered by which button. I'll add a little pseudo-code to the end of my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help, it helped point me in the right direction!